# Java spark accessing emc object store through S3 API

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

Can I get a reference for the apis of Java+ spark sql accessing emc object store via S3 api. I tried many S3 apis(aws-java-sdk.1.7.4 jar) but stuck in some error related to bucket name.(Because my bucket name contains "*" underscore. My object store on emc which allows bucket names with "*". But I want to access this by spark sql but through S3 api.

Answer (score 0):

Trouble is that the S3A connectors all expect bucket name to be a valid hostname, but _ isn't allowed in DNS names.

AWS now [forbid new buckets with underscores](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html), and the people who do the S3 connectors for tools like spark aren't going to do anything with bug reports about this other than close as "wontfix".

Sorry, but you'll just have to rename your bucket.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I got the answer. I debugged AWS code and found that AWS connector uses java URI internally to retrive the host name from the bucket URL (the host name is the bucket name actually) and it does not accept underscore which creates the problem. So I changed my bucket name. Thanks.